# Send tsql values from c# using variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to send `NULL` values to stored procedure trought C#, so I  have something like:

```
var projName = chkByName.Checked ? sFilter : "NULL";
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? sFilter : "NULL";

var sql = $"exec getDesignListByProject  @ProjName ='{projName}', @Folio ='{designFolio}'
```

Once I have the SQL query, I just execute SQL method as:

```
 var tvTable = db.GetDataSet(sql, "tvTable").Tables["tvTable"];
```

`GetDataSet` method:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, string TableName)
{
    this._Errors = false;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), this.dbconn);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        da.Fill(ds, TableName);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetDataSet", sql);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But if I send parameters with NULL string as above I send to SQL something like

```
exec getDesignListByProject  @ProjName ='NULL',@Folio='NULL'
```

But is a string instead `NULL` SQL value

So I try to change my variable to:

```
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? sFilter : DBNull.Value.ToString();
```

But I just receive null string like:

```
exec getDesignListByProject  @Folio=''
```

How can I send NULL T-SQL values? Regards

Comment: no need to convert "DBNull.Value.ToString();". you can simply send DBNull.Value

Comment: I try it but I get  = Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DBNull' @Gauravsa

Comment: can you do (object)DBNull.Value

Comment: You should be using a SqlCommand object with a stored procedure call and properly typed parameters. This `"EXEC procedure '{token}';"` stuff is messy, error-prone, not great for plan cache/reuse, and potentially vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SP call to.

```
var projName = chkByName.Checked ? $"'{sFilter}'" : "NULL";
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? $"'{sFilter}'" : "NULL";

var sql = $"exec getDesignListByProject  @ProjName ={projName}, @Folio ={designFolio}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `null` to string variable

```
string str = null;
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? sFilter : str ;
```

or

```
string str = DBNull.Value 
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? sFilter : str ;
```

Comment: If I send null as you say I just sending it like my second case: `exec getDesignListByProject  @Folio=''` , instead `exec getDesignListByProject  @Folio= NULL`, If I try your second recomendation in `str string` I just get error: `convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var projName = chkByName.Checked ? sFilter : (object)DBNull.Value;
var designFolio = chkByDesign.Checked ? sFilter : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Your stored procedure can look like this:

```
create procedure getDesignListByProject
(@projName int = NULL,
@folio int = null)
```

So, even if you don't pass anything, it will have null value. Then you can use NULL functions like Coalesce and ISNULL etc.

Also,

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), this.dbconn);
```

No need to convert `sql.ToString()`. Its already a string.

Comment: I try exactly that, but it's same result as my last try I just get something like `exec getDesignListByProject  @Folio=''` instead `exec getDesignListByProject  @Folio=NULL`

Comment: edited the answer to provide some more info which can help